# How to automate conversion of C++ file to Wireshark Lua dissector

Tags: c++, lua, wireshark-dissector

I have a C++ file defining a certain protocol. The file contains structs which define the messages used in the protocol. Each struct contains fields for a certain message. An example would be as follows:

```
struct STATS00_MESSAGE_T
{
    uint8_t  message_type
    uint16_t num_sends;
    uint8_t  num_failures;
};
```

What is the best or easiest way to convert a C++ file containing a lot of structs like these into a Lua dissector for Wireshark? The Lua dissector should be able to dissect the fields of the messages.

The C++ file is quite complex containing several enums, typedefs, Boost macros, includes, etc. So, writing a brute-force parsing script like Perl to do the automated conversion from C++ to Lua dissector is not that easy to do. Are there existing tools we can use to facilitate the conversion process?

Comment: Can you modify the C++? I'd be tempted to pull the interesting bits out into a separate file (making them a little easier to parse), or perhaps even have a separate script generate both the C++ and lua versions of the structures.

Comment: (also, I'm impressed by your dedication; still banging your head against this problem after 18 months!)

Comment: Thanks, Rook. Yes, we can modify the C++ file. The C++ file, however, is being shared/edited by a lot of other engineers. So setting up new rules on editing the C++ file is a little complicated as we would have to teach/reinforce the other engineers on how to edit/generate the file. Also the C++ file is tightly coupled with and used by a lot of other C++ files. So auto-generating the C++ file may be a little complicated but probably possible.

Comment: The generation of the lua and C++ output files is something that could be tied into your build system, at least. It doesn't require the use of sophisticated tools, after all. (also, if the source changes infrequently, and isn't modified by many people, you can always stick the output files in your version control system with a note saying "don't modify these by hand", which could make life easier for various team members who only consume the file)