# How to get the order of the members of a struct using SWIG

Tags: c++, lua, swig

Given a C++ struct, using SWIG, I am able to get the names of the members of the struct in Lua (see this blog [entry](https://nonbonding.blogspot.com/2017/06/swig-for-lua-reflection.html)). Unfortunately, I noticed that my retrieval of the member names does not provide accurate information about the order by which the members were declared in the C++ struct definition.

Is there a way to obtain the declared order of the members of a C++ struct using SWIG in Lua?

Comment: Can you rewind a bit and explain why it matters what order they were declared in? There's probably a much better answer to the underlying motivating question you've not show. Even when you know the order you still don't know padding/alignment, so it doesn't let you safely do anything else. And from the POV of a SWIG wrapper you shouldn't need to know - SWIG itself might not even know the actual order, or the complete picture.

Comment: Hi Flexo, I'm trying to think of a solution for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705116/how-to-automate-conversion-of-c-file-to-wireshark-lua-dissector  And I thought that SWIG might be a good solution.

Comment: That make sense. You can probably do that with SWIG if you're able to shift the focus somewhat away from layout. Probably more accurate and simpler overall would be to use [DWARF](https://github.com/aperezdc/lua-eol)/PDB to query the actual layout and skip SWIG entirely. I'll have a think about it.